# Why doesn't show markers in processing using unfoldingmaps?

Tags: maps, processing, markers

I want to maker a marker. I use mac.
 I try to make this by processing. And I use an unfoldingmap library. 
 But a marker doesn't show.

Additionally, I draw a text for knowing my position. But It doesn't show.

Thank you for your answer!

```java
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.geo.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.utils.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.marker.*;

UnfoldingMap map;


void setup()  {
size(800,600);

map=new UnfoldingMap(this,new Google.GoogleMapProvider());


MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this,map);

Location seoulLocation=new Location(37.549,126.989);

map.zoomAndPanTo(seoulLocation,10);
float maxPanningDistance=30;  //in km
map.setPanningRestriction(seoulLocation,maxPanningDistance);


SimplePointMarker seoulMarker=new SimplePointMarker(seoulLocation);
//SimplePointMarker dublinMarker=new SimplePointMarker(dublinLocation);

map.addMarkers(seoulMarker);

map.setTweening(true);
}

void draw()  {
map.draw(); 

// position showing
Location location=map.getLocation(mouseX,mouseY);
fill(100);
text(location.getLat()+","+location.getLon(),mouseX,mouseY);
}
```

I try to show my mouse position in draw fucntion.but It doesn't show. 
   But if I delete "map.draw()", then I can show. But I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, both things show up.

The marker is here:

[image]

You can zoom in to see it better:

[image]

Similarly, I also see the text. In this screenshot, my mouse is just to the right of the marker:

[image]

If this is not what you're seeing, then check the console are of the Processing editor for any errors.

Comment: Thank you. I can know that it is working well in "processing-2 ". But when I use "processing-3", then it is not working.

Comment: @김진형 Unfolding Maps does not support Processing 3 yet. You'll have to stick to Processing 2 for now.